# Always Defer a Field in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-managers

How do I make a field on a Django model deferred for all queries of that model without needing to put a defer on every query?

## Research

This was [requested as a feature in 2014 and rejected in 2022](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23816).

Baring such a feature native to Django, the obvious idea is to make a custom manager like this:

```
class DeferedFieldManager(models.Manager):

    def __init__(self, defered_fields=[]):
        super().__init__()
        self.defered_fields = defered_fields

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs
            ).defer(*self.defered_fields)

class B(models.Model):
    pass

class A(models.Model):
    big_field = models.TextField(null=True)
    b = models.ForeignKey(B, related_name="a_s")

    objects = DeferedFieldManager(["big_field"])

class C(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)

class D(models.Model):
    a = models.OneToOneField(A)

class E(models.Model):
    a_s = models.ManyToManyField(A)
```

However, while this works for `A.objects.first()` (direct lookups), it doesn't work for `B.objects.first().a_s.all()` (one-to-manys), `C.objects.first().a` (many-to-ones), `D.objects.first().a` (one-to-ones), or `E.objects.first().a_s.all()` (many-to-manys).

The thing I find particularly confusing here is that this is the default manager for my object, which means it should also be the default for the reverse lookups (the one-to-manys and many-to-manys), yet this isn't working.  Per the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#using-a-custom-reverse-manager):

> By default the RelatedManager used for reverse relations is a subclass of the default manager for that model.

An easy way to test this is to drop the field that should be deferred from the database, and the code will only error with an `OperationalError: no such column` if the field is not properly deferred.  To test, do the following steps:

1. Data setup:

   ```
   b = B.objects.create()
   a = A.objects.create(b=b)
   c = C.objects.create(a=a)
   d = D.objects.create(a=a)
   e = E.objects.create()
   e.a_s.add(a)
   ```
2. Comment out `big_field`
3. `manage.py makemigrations`
4. `manage.py migrate`
5. Comment in `big_field`
6. Run tests:

   ```
   from django.db import OperationalError
   def test(test_name, f, attr=None):
       try:
           if attr:
               x = getattr(f(), attr)
           else:
               x = f()
           assert isinstance(x, A)
           print(f"{test_name}:\tpass")
       except OperationalError:
           print(f"{test_name}:\tFAIL!!!")

   test("Direct Lookup", A.objects.first)
   test("One-to-Many", B.objects.first().a_s.first)
   test("Many-to-One", C.objects.first, "a")
   test("One-to-One", D.objects.first, "a")
   test("Many-to-Many", E.objects.first().a_s.first)
   ```

If the tests above all pass, the field has been properly deferred.

I'm currently getting:

```
Direct Lookup:  pass
One-to-Many:    FAIL!!!
Many-to-One:    FAIL!!!
One-to-One:     FAIL!!!
Many-to-Many:   FAIL!!!
```

## Partial Answer

[@aaron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73938166/2800876) solves half of the failing cases.

If I change `A` to have:

```
class Meta:
    base_manager_name = 'objects'
```

I now get the following from tests:

```
Direct Lookup:  pass
One-to-Many:    FAIL!!!
Many-to-One:    pass
One-to-One:     pass
Many-to-Many:   FAIL!!!
```

This still does not work for the revere lookups.

Comment: Storing the data for `big_field` in another model and replacing the field with a `OneToOneField` to the new model, while not answering the question, may be a work-around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `Meta.base_manager_name` to `'objects'`.

```py
class A(models.Model):
    big_field = models.TextField(null=True)
    b = models.ForeignKey(B, related_name="a_s")

    objects = DeferedFieldManager(["big_field"])

    class Meta:
        base_manager_name = 'objects'
```

From https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/managers/#using-managers-for-related-object-access:

> ##### Using managers for related object access
>
> By default, Django uses an instance of the `Model._base_manager` manager class when accessing related objects (i.e. `choice.question`), not the `_default_manager` on the related object. This is because Django needs to be able to retrieve the related object, even if it would otherwise be filtered out (and hence be inaccessible) by the default manager.
>
> If the normal base manager class (`django.db.models.Manager`) isn’t appropriate for your circumstances, you can tell Django which class to use by setting `Meta.base_manager_name`.

## Reverse Many-to-One and Many-to-Many managers

The "One-To-Many" case in the question is a Reverse Many-To-One.

Django subclasses the manager class to override the behaviour, and then instantiates it — without the `defered_fields` argument passed to `__init__` since
`django.db.models.Manager` and its subclasses are not expected to have parameters.

Thus, you need something like:

```py
def make_defered_field_manager(defered_fields):
    class DeferedFieldManager(models.Manager):
        def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).defer(*defered_fields)
    return DeferedFieldManager()
```

Usage:

```py
# objects = DeferedFieldManager(["big_field"])
objects = make_defered_field_manager(["big_field"])
```

Answer (score -1):

This is works on Django 1.4.22, i use it in admin-panel, to made the answer from DB smaller:

```
C.objects.select_related('a').defer('a__some_field').first()
```

And it should works too (not tested):

```
D.objects.select_related('a').defer('a__some_field').first()
```

We have created custom queryset methods, in your case:

```
class C_obj_queryset(QuerySet):
    
    def get_deferred_for_related_model(self, model):
        return self.select_related(model).defer(*model.objects.defered_fields)
```

more here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#defer

> You can defer loading of fields in related models (if the related models are loading via select_related()) by using the standard
> double-underscore notation to separate related fields.

Comment: Deferring on `select_related` is interesting, but this still requires putting a defer call on every query (which the question specifically rules out as a viable solution).